# cout vector<vector<int>> more succinctly

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> v1 = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    vector<vector<int>> v2 = { {5, 6}, {7, 8} };
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        transform(v1[i].begin(), v1[i].end(), v2[i].begin(), v1[i].begin(), plus<int>());
    }
    for (const auto& i : v1)
    {
        for (const auto& j : i)
        {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to print the vectors with more succinct code? With something from  `algorithm` for example. Thank you.

> Output:
>
> 6 8
>
> 10 12

**Edit:**
I don't want to write anything new or overload operators.

Comment: Not really for the outer vector, but for the inner there's [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator). And of course you can always overload `operator<<` to take `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` as argument.

Comment: You can write an `ostream& operator <<(ostream& s, const vector<T>& v)` that uses `ostream_iterator<T>(s, " ")`, and then `ostream_iterator<vector<int>>(cout, "\n")` will do the whole thing

Comment: OK, so I changed the inner loop to use `ostream_iterator`. Thanks! :) I don't want to write anything new or overload operators. I add this to the original post.

Comment: Aside: I would write a function `vector<> elementwise_plus(const vector<> &, const vector<> &)` that contains the body of your first loop, and then replace that loop with  `transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v1.begin(), elementwise_plus);` ( or similar with `for_each` and a non-const reference in the lhs )

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
for(const auto& i : v1) {
    using V = std::decay<decltype(i)>::type::value_type;
    std::copy(i.begin(), i.end(), std::ostream_iterator<V>(std::cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

IMO, the loops are simpler to read.

Comment: You don't need std::decay with the sample code right, but with you code you can iterate over nut just integers? I don't really understand that line. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @bencemeszaros `decltype(i)` is `std::vector<int> const&` which doesn't have embedded type `value_type`. Hence `std::decay` is necessary to remove `const&`.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks. I'm not familiar with `std::decay` and `decltype`. Do you know any exercises to get familiar with them?

Comment: @bencemeszaros Here: [std::decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) / [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)